# System.Data.TypedTableBase methods not accessible outside project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, xsd

I have migrated a DataSet XSD file from VS2005 to VS2013.  I am consequently unable to access DataTable methods like SELECT and MERGE outside of the project in another project, though it works fine inside that project.

I note that in the original version (VS2005, VB.NET), the XSD generates a DataTable.

```
Partial Public Class ConfigDataTable
Inherits Global.System.Data.DataTable
Implements Global.System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

But in VS2013 (C#), a `System.Data.TypedTableBase<T>` is generated.  I'm not sure if this is relevant.

```
    public class ConfigDataTable : System.Data.TypedTableBase<EOL_Cached.ConfigRow>
```

I only found this one [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98a14780-8b94-4d3d-8f06-c7a390c61cbd/systemdatatypedtablebase-methods-not-accessible?forum=netfxbcl) (re-posted many times) on the Internet that appears to be the same exact issue I'm having. Note I do have a proper reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll as was suggested in the post reply.

I also note in Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358258(v=vs.100).aspx) on TypedTableBase that the class "is not intended to be used directly from your code.".  If that is the case, how am I to use a DataSet properly in a modern context?

Can anyone advise why I can't see SELECT and MERGE methods outside of that project inside my ASP.NET project where it is being consumed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The `TypedTableBase(Of T)` class inherits `DataTable` so there's no reason that I'm aware of that you should not be able to access members of the `DataTable` class on an instance of your `ConfigDataTable` class.

Comment: I agree and have confirmed via Microsoft documentation as linked to above, but the issue remains that I can't see these DataTable methods outside of the project the class is in and I can't explain why.

Comment: Can you cast an instance as type `DataTable`?